# How to debug functions they called via eval etc

Tags: r

I dont know how to debug structures like:

```
fun1 <- function(obj){
   a<-c(obj,4)
   c(a,5)
}

fun <- function(obj){
   a <- match.call()
   a[[1L]] <- fun1
   return(eval.parent(a))
}
```

I would like to know how to instruct the debug-mode to follow the call `eval.parent(a)` and jump into `fun1`.

Comment: There's an awful lot of unnecessary code here.  You will get better answers (and better understand the problem yourself) if you boil it down to a minimally reproducible answer: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269/how-to-make-a-great-r-reproducible-example

Comment: I split up the most interesting part of my problem I hope that makes it easier to read it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Per the debug help page: "If you want to debug a function not starting at the very beginning, use `trace(..., at = *)` or `setBreakpoint`."

```
> trace(eval.parent)

> fun(4)
trace: eval.parent(a)
[1] 4 4 5
```

Or perhaps you want to raise a warning and use that to trigger the browser. Hard to tell at this point what you are expecting.